# Make Tooltip of WPF slider stay on screen while dragging

Tags: wpf, xaml, slider, wpf-style

I am using a slider control to set the zoom level of an application and i want to show the current zoom  level as live to end user.
So i decided to show a tooltip on top of slider so user can see the value of zoom level.

But the problem is when user drag the position of slider the Tooltip disappears and i cant see the Tooltip again. I have to change position of mouse an dagain i have to place mouse on top of slider to see what the zoom level is

The xaml i used is this

```
<Slider                                        
    VerticalAlignment="Center"                                             
    Minimum="50" Maximum="200" Width="150"  Name="ViewZoomlevel" 
    IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"   
    Thumb.DragStarted="ViewZoomlevel_DragStarted" Thumb.DragCompleted="ViewZoomlevel_DragCompleted"                                         
        >
    <Slider.ToolTip >
        <ToolTip StaysOpen="True" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="12000" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                    Path=PlacementTarget.Value}" 
                    ContentStringFormat="Zoom: {0:0} %" />
    </Slider.ToolTip>
</Slider>
```

I applied ToolTipService.ShowDuration="12000" But it seems to have no effect.
How can i make sure the Slider Tooltip appears there on top of slider while Dragging the position of Slider Thumb

Comment: Try `StaysOpen=True` for your `ToolTip`.

Comment: A tooltip obviously isn't the right kind of control. A tooltip has a very clearly defined mode of operation: appear over a control when you first move mouse over it and then disappear. To reappear you need to move mouse away and back again. What you want is something that doesn't behave like this, so why not just create your own popup or textblock that appears/disappears when you dictate?

Answer (score 5):

There is solution without 'code behind'

Implementation of custom Popup control:

```
public class PopupEx : Popup
{
    protected override void OnOpened(EventArgs e)
    {
        var friend = this.PlacementTarget;
        friend.QueryCursor += friend_QueryCursor;

        base.OnOpened(e);
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        var friend = this.PlacementTarget;
        friend.QueryCursor -= friend_QueryCursor;

        base.OnClosed(e);
    }

    private void friend_QueryCursor(object sender, System.Windows.Input.QueryCursorEventArgs e)
    {
        this.HorizontalOffset += +0.1;
        this.HorizontalOffset += -0.1;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Slider.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                <Grid Background="#05000000">
                    <PopupEx x:Name="InfoPopup" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Thumb}" Placement="Top" StaysOpen="False" IsOpen="False" AllowsTransparency="True">
                        <Border Padding="2" CornerRadius="3" Background="#555C5C5C">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding ElementName=PART_Track, Path=Value, StringFormat=Zoom:{0:0}%}"></TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                    </PopupEx>
                    <Track x:Name="PART_Track">
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Width="10" Height="20">
                            </Thumb>
                        </Track.Thumb>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsDragging" Value="True">
                        <Setter Value="True" TargetName="InfoPopup" Property="IsOpen" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsDragging" Value="False">
                        <Setter Value="False" TargetName="InfoPopup" Property="IsOpen" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Slider.Template>
    </Slider>
```

[image: slider with tooltip result]

Comment: Most re-usable answer. Thanks!

Comment: Most helpful answer to me! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [AutoToolTipPlacement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.slider.autotooltipplacement) property. Set it to `TopLeft` For it to appear above your cursor.

```
<Slider AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case try use [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<Grid>
    <Slider Name="MySlider"                                       
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Minimum="50" Maximum="200" Width="150"
            IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" />

    <Popup Name="MyPopup"
           IsOpen="False"
           StaysOpen="True"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MySlider}"
           PlacementRectangle="150,0,0,0">
        <Grid Background="AliceBlue">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MySlider, Path=Value}" />
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

You can also add `IsOpen="True"` and `IsOpen="False"` in `Slider` events:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MySlider_DragStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void MySlider_DragCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyPopup.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to Open it ? On DragChange event do i need to call code Popup.Isopen=true;?? Then when i wil cal code to hide Popup??.The tooltip automatically handle it